# How to obtain an Azure B2C bearer token for a non-interactive/daemon application and get it validated in an Azure HTTP-triggered function

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

There is a C# application under development that is supposed to be a part of a bigger backend application to process some data. This application is supposed to obtain a token from Azure AD B2C and send it to an HTTP-triggered function where it is supposed to be validated by the following code:

```cs
var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                            $"{_authenticationSettings.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
                        var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
                        _validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            // Audience MUST be the app ID aka clientId
                            ValidAudience = _authenticationSettings.ClientId,
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
                            ValidateLifetime = true
                        };

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var result = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authHeader.Parameter, _validationParameters, out var jwtToken);
```

First, we thought that obtaining an access token from Microsoft Graph API using MSAL would help us but the C# code above threw an invalid signature exception which we discovered makes sense due to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-524434987). Apparently, we need to obtain an `id_token` instead in the application and send it to the HTTP-triggered function for validation by the code snippet above.

The application cannot obtain the `id_token` because it's not supposed to launch Azure AD B2C's login UI to have a user sign-in and redirect it through a URL. What is the solution to this problem so that the application would obtain a token without a UI and send that to the http-triggered function for validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining a token for the AAD B2C tenant without UI is possible in two ways and you should probably pick one depending on what exactly you want to achieve:

1. user token - by using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy. This flow is deprecated though and mentioned usually in legacy application context
2. server-side application token - by using Client Cretendial flow  - this on the other hand requires using requests specific for AAD but with AAD B2C tenant - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications

I'm also not quite sure why should you use id_token for that. If the application needs to authorize the request to the function with the token then it should be an access token regardless of how the token is retrieved (interactive UI or not).

Comment: I can discard using id_token.

Comment: I could not find an example to verify the token in an Azure Function. The client app in the example is Web Api. Any directions on that?